# How to use Puppeteer for getting lattitude and longitude of restaurants

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, puppeteer

I want to scrape the data from the following website:-
https://food.grab.com/sg/en/

These are the steps I want to implement

1. Type "Singapore" (or any location in Singapore) in the input box.
2. Click on the search button.
3. Click on the load more button until it is not disabled or disappeared. (This will load all the restaurants related to "Singapore")
4. Click on each restaurant.
5. Get the lat lang data from network tab
6. click back

Following is my code:

```js
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer");

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  await page.goto("https://food.grab.com/sg/en/");
  await page.type("input", "Singapore");
  await page.click(".submitBtn___2roqB");
  //click on load_more while it is not disabled


  //click on every restaurant
  //get the lat lang data from network tab
  //go back

  const elHandleArr = await page.$$(".realImage___2TyNE show___3oA6B");
  let arr = [];

  elHandleArr.map(async (el) => {
    await el.evaluate((b) => b.click());
    page.on("request", (req) => {
      console.log(req.headers());
      arr.push(req.headers());
    });
    await page.goBack();
    page.waitFor(1000);
  });

  console.log(arr);

  // await browser.close();
})();
```

So I am able to perform the first two steps but not able to click on the load more button and not able to click on restaurants.

Comment: Does anyone know if "run code snippet" added automatically? This is node.js code, not client-side JS, and can't run in a browser window.

Comment: @barrycarter Yes this is node.js code so one would need some code editor , I am using Vs code, run code snippet was added automatically

Comment: I assume you're looking for the promos, not just a list of restaurants. If you just need a list of restaurants, openstreetmaps.org is the way to go

Comment: It's not added automatically, just that some people don't realize that code fences should be used instead of adding a JS snippet for code that can't run in the browser.